# All the values of my one of axis is not showing(only some of them are displaying on graph) up and i'm getting a false graph in python plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I Have two Array pf shape(28,)

```
train_auc=[0.6126523684334859, 0.6126523684334859, 0.6126523684334859, 0.6126523684334859, 0.7492382986168273, 0.7492150720394141, 0.7483846483781261, 0.7468934829965687, 0.8297123881389865, 0.8282774000774683, 0.819465324480643, 0.8089592548975469, 0.9815200265455036, 0.9765725084545359, 0.945900017818138, 0.9032596274172816, 0.9950833197856929, 0.9911603111171855, 0.9656495707711237, 0.9201576327214571, 0.999568305039995, 0.9980621479688683, 0.977842999420234, 0.9343008824016726, 0.9995782986320118, 0.9979981869609026, 0.9777291109842698, 0.9334552475828799]

cv_auc=[0.606349991836311, 0.606349991836311, 0.606349991836311, 0.606349991836311, 0.73513531806795, 0.7350383639905016, 0.7355188075454178, 0.7374102828179758, 0.7661341879179244, 0.7655935838823974, 0.7727780669707792, 0.7787067996380197, 0.7212937201033887, 0.7235450710098645, 0.7615920275708545, 0.7975782731350783, 0.7020487552541194, 0.7081813641892084, 0.7498443890574792, 0.7829337245130458, 0.6871793378908755, 0.6932093326091239, 0.7321988693967574, 0.7643627769134962, 0.6883374232190598, 0.6936318254010602, 0.732650956548267, 0.764961248815501]

max_depth=[1,5,10,50,100,500,1000]
min_samples_split=[5,10,100,500]
```

I need a 3d plot between these The code i used is

```
import plotly.offline as offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
offline.init_notebook_mode()


x1 = min_samples_split
y1 = max_depth
z1 = train_auc
x2 = min_samples_split
y2 = max_depth
z2 = cv_auc
trace1 = go.Scatter3d(x=x1,y=y1,z=z1, name = 'train')
trace2 = go.Scatter3d(x=x2,y=y2,z=z2, name = 'Cross validation')
data = [trace1, trace2]

layout = go.Layout(scene = dict(
        xaxis = dict(title='min_samples_split'),
        yaxis = dict(title='max_depth'),
        zaxis = dict(title='AUC'),))

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
offline.iplot(fig, filename='3d-scatter-colorscale')
```

The Output i get is [This Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqDwi.png)

And on this plot if you see the AUC values they are only showing 0.608,0.61,0.612 While in train auc there are uto 0.99
How should i correct this?

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).